# how do i change the order receipt page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

once you've placed an order with magento you taking to a final page that confirms your order. How can i edit the content of this page. ie just need to add a line of copy.

Comment: Do you mean the last step of the "one page checkout" or the success page that says "your order has been placed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template checkout files can be found at this location
(where you might have to substitute the default with a template name)
/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout